# JQuery: Storying HTML block in var

Tags: jquery

```
var anotherListItem = '<div class= "form-list"> 
                         <button class= "done"></button> 
                         <input type= "text"> 
                       </div>'
```

This is not working. I've also tried to include a backslash at every `'` like so: `'/<div… </div>/'` but it doesn't help. 
How can I fix this?

Comment: well you need to remove the space between the class=  <-- get rid of the space (close the gap) and at the very end of the statement you need a ;       var anotherListItem = '<div class="form-list"> <button class="done"></button> <input type="text"></div>';

Comment: This `\` is a backslash and `/` is a slash or forward slash. Put ibackquotes around inline code, and especially around HTML as the [so] system otherwise thinks its markup.

Comment: I appreciate your help too!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating multiline strings in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805107/creating-multiline-strings-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Put the whole thing on one line like this:**

```
var anotherListItem = '<div class="form-list"><button class="done"></button><input type="text"></div>';
```

**For multiple lines, you'd have to use string concatenation:**

```
var anotherListItem2 = '<div class="form-list">'+ 
                         '<button class="done"></button>'+  
                         '<input type="text">'+  
                       '</div>'
```

Remember, if you want to bind a click handler or similar to a dynamically added element, you have to use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Below is a contrived example:

```js
$('#container').on('click','.done', function(){
  alert('this works');
  
  });
var anotherListItem = '<div class="form-list"><button class="done">press me</button><input type="text"></div>';
$('#container').append( anotherListItem );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: I actually started off with a one-liner. It worked at first, but no longer now. :T

Comment: @munmay what do you mean by "it doesnt work" ? the above does work, what are you trying to do with it after you create the variable?

Comment: @munmay are you by chance trying to bind a click handler to the "done" button?

Comment: I was trying to add the elements in the variable after "enter" is pushed. This solution worked and it turns out I was having issues elsewhere. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

```
var anotherListItem = "<div class= 'form-list'>"+ 
                     "<button class= 'done'></button>"+ 
                     "<input type= 'text'>"+ 
                  "</div>"
```

This is the fiddle , if you want line break put a "\n"

http://jsfiddle.net/dea5h3eh/

Comment: You should wrap your string in single quotes and use the normal double quotes to wrap the properties. Additionally, using `\n` for a line break would only work if being displayed in an alert or similar, as this is an `html` string and likely to be inserted in the `dom` you should use `<br>` for a a line break. See http://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/dea5h3eh/1/